# Only first validation rule working

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0

I have a set of validation rules I am imposing on my model in Cakephp 2.0 and since they are all for fields that deal with web addresses, they are exactly the same.  Cut and pasted exact.  However, when I modify my db in my edit form, only the first rule works;  all the others validate and update my record.  Here is my model code:

```
public $validate=array(
    'unit_website'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'rates'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'book'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    ),
    'contact'=>array(
        'rule'=>'url',
        'message'=>'You must enter a valid website address.'
    )
);
```

**UPDATE***  Here is my form:

```
<?php    
echo $this->Form->create('Unit', array(
    'action' => 'edit',
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
        )
    )
);
echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
echo $this->Form->hidden('location_id');
echo $this->Form->hidden('Location.id');
echo $this->Form->hidden('Location.lat');
echo $this->Form->hidden('Location.lon');
echo $this->Form->input('Location.prop_name', array('label'=>'Property name where your unit is located', 'div'=>true));
if($this->data['Unit']['type']=='condo' || $this->data['Unit']['type']=='house') {
echo $this->Form->input('Unit.unitnum', array('label' => 'Unit\'s Name/Number'));
}
echo $this->Form->input('type', array('label'=>'Type of Property',    'onChange'=>'toggle()', 'options'=>array('condo'=>'Condo', 'house'=>'House',   'hotel'=>'Hotel or Motel', 'rentalco'=>'This is a rental company')));
 echo $this->Form->input('Location.address', array('onChange'=>'getLatLong(address)',  'size'=>'50', 'div'=>true));
echo $this->Form->input('Location.city', array('onChange'=>'getLatLong(address)'));
echo $this->Form->input('Location.state', array('onChange'=>'getLatLong(address)',  'size'=>'2'));
echo $this->Form->input('Location.zip', array('size'=>'5'));
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('Location.area_code', array('size'=>'3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Location.exchange', array('size'=>'3'));
echo $this->Form->input('Location.sln', array('size'=>'4'));
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('unit_website', array('size'=>'65', 'label'=>'Your unit\'s   website', 'error' => array('class' => 'error')));
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('specials', array('label' => 'Your website\'s Specials page',  'size'=>'65', 'error' => array('class' => 'error')));
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('rates', array('size'=>'65', 'error' => array('class' =>  'error'), 'label'=>'Your unit\'s rates page'));
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('book', array('size'=>'65', 'error' => array('class' =>  'error'), 'label'=>'Your unit\'s booking page or calendar'));
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('contact', array('size'=>'65', 'error' => array('class' =>  'error'), 'label'=>'Your unit\'s contact or email page'));
echo '<br />';
if($this->data['Unit']['type']=='condo' || $this->data['Unit']['type']=='house') {
echo '<br /><div id="unit_info">';
echo $this->Form->input('sq_ft', array('label'=>'Square feet', 'min'=>'1000',  'max'=>'10000', 'step'=>'50'));
echo $this->Form->input('bedrooms', array('label'=>'Bedrooms', 'min'=>'1', 'max'=>'15', 'step'=>'1'));
echo $this->Form->input('baths', array('label'=>'Bathrooms', 'min'=>'1', 'max'=>'10', 'step'=>'.5'));
echo $this->Form->input('sleeps', array('label'=>'How many people does your unit sleep?', 'min'=>'1', 'max'=>'45', 'step'=>'1'));
echo '</div><br />';
echo $this->Form->input('unit_desc', array('div'=>true, 'cols'=>'150', 'rows'=>'4',  'label'=>'Describe your unit <span style="font-size:14px; font-style:italic">(Remember to  include the sizes of beds in each bedroom, whether you have a sleeper sofa, deluxe kitchens  and baths, balconies and their views, access to amenities, and any other items that  distinguish your property.)</span>'));
}
else {
echo '<br />';
echo $this->Form->input('unit_desc', array('div'=>true, 'cols'=>'150', 'rows'=>'4',  'label'=>'Describe your hotel or rental company'));
}
echo '<br />&nbsp;';
echo $this->Form->end('Update Property');?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

Does Cake have some sort of "you can only make this rule once" rule?  Or do my model field names have to actually have the word website in them or something?  Or have I just made some dumb syntax error?

**UPDATE**   Here is my controller code:

```
function edit($id) {
$this->set('title', 'Edit your property');
$this->Unit->id = $id;    
if (empty($this->data)) {        
$this->data = $this->Unit->read();    
} else { 

    if ($this->Unit->saveAll($this->data)) {            
        $this->Session->setFlash('Your property has been updated.', 'success');            

        }   
}
}
```

Comment: Will you show the controller and then entire form? For example, I would like to see your form->create() call in the view. I would also like to see the controller method for handling the edit.

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL you are validating and what are you expecting? The `url` validation will not check for protocol unless you specify it. If you want to make sure `http` is in the url, you should specify your rule like this:

```
'rule' => array('url', true)
```

Please show sample URLs that are passing validation but are not valid.

**UPDATE**

`$this->data` should be changed to `$this->request->data`. This may not change the validation process. But `$this->data` is deprecated.

Try adding a `beforeValidate` callback in the `Unit` model and echo `$this->data` to see what is coming through.

Comment: things like 1234 and $thisisnotddata.  These are passing validation and going into the database.  However, if I try entering 1234 or $notdata or whatever into the 'unit_website' (the first rule in the array and the first form field for an url) I get my error message and it does not validate.  I do not expect any particular url in these fields, just any valid url.

Comment: So for some reason (I swear I haven't touched this code since we spoke!), all but ONE of the validation rules works, and get this...now the error messages no longer display...on any form elements for model Unit.  All form elements for model Location...the error message displays normally when validation fails.  I think my copy of Cake is just haunted, that's all.